# Can't Upgrade Ubuntu the System

Tags: boot, upgrade

The upgrade needs a total of 27.4 M free space on disk '/boot'. Please free at least an additional 9,027 k of disk space on '/boot'. Empty your trash and remove temporary packages of former installations using 'sudo apt-get clean'.

How to get free space for installing new updates? 
I checked the boot in the file system. There were different versions of the same thing. Can I just delete older versions by myself to get free space?

Answer (score 0):

It is a good idea to use

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

from time to time. Apt-get manpage says:

```
autoremove
     autoremove is used to remove packages that were automatically
     installed to satisfy dependencies for other packages and are now no
     longer needed.
```

This removes "remainings" of previous kernel versions and I'd bet it should free enough disk space in your case, too.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply remove some of the old boot files, and then run `upgrade-grub`. For example:

```
cd /boot
ls vmlinuz-*
```

Say, if you have

```
vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic
vmlinuz-3.2.0-57-generic
```

and want to remove all files with version 3.2.0-57, you could do:

```
sudo -s
remove *-3.2.0-57-*
update-grub
```

The last command fixes the grub boot menu to reflect the changes you've made.